# how to get first frame from Camera capture in opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get only first frame from the video, which is capture by the webcam.
If anyone know how to do it please help me

Thank you...

Comment: Have you at least checked the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)?

Comment: keep in mind sometimes the first captured image by webcam is too dark.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto Video_URL = "c:/sample.mp4";
cv::VideoCapture cap(Video_URL);
cv::Mat frame;

if (cap.read(frame)){
    //Do something with frame
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but I want get first frame and keep it separate from other frames